# Installing PyMC3 on Anaconda 3 / Win

Tags: pymc3, pymc

This installation is a nightmare!!!

Using:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pymc3
```

Will not work.

I then tried to install theano first (and its dependencies), found out the hard way that it works with python=3.5, NOT 3.6.

```
# Install theano reqirements
conda install numpy scipy mkl-service libpython m2w64-toolchain

# Install theano
conda install theano pygpu

# You are using a different python version (3.5) from the base installation,
# you must point to the right kernel for Jupyter:
conda install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user

# Install & test on jupyter, spyder
conda install jupyter spyder qt

# Install PyMC3
pip install pymc3
```

Everything imports, but then when I run the code the 'NUTS' thing won't initialize...

Comment: Are you running a default example? Are you seeing an error or is it just hanging? It would help if you included a simple model that you are trying to run and is not working for you.

Comment: @merv: please give me a default sample to run.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which process worked for me but this is the step I took

1. reset my whole laptop
2. re-download wsl2
3. install conda
4. go to this directory

> path_to_your_python_env>/Lib/site-packages/theano/misc/windows.py

5. delete or comment out following

> params['shell'] = True

6. Even though it works, the compiler is extremely still slows